# Geocoding in python-API Key

Tags: python, api, geocoding

I know it's a  very simple question but does anyone know or can tell me where should I put my API Key in this small program and how?

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error
import json

service = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True :
 address = input('Enter a location:')
 if len(address) < 1 :
    break
 url = service + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address' : address})

 print('Retrieving',url)
 urll = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 data = urll.read().decode()
 print('Retrieved',len(data),'Characters')

 try:
     js = json.loads(data)
 except :
     js = None 

 if not js or 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK' :
     print('===Faield===')
     print (data)
     continue

 lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
 lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
 print('lat',lat,"lng",lng)
 location = js["results"][0]["formatted_address"]  
 print(location)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Last_Fox according to [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) use your Api key like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: can you tell me how to?

Comment: @Last_Fox i have updated my answer please take a look

Comment: it says that there is no such a file or directory in 'with open(f'{dir_path}/config.json') as config_file:' , I don't know if you understood what I meant with my question  but I meant when I run my program it says you need to use an API key, I made a one from Google platforms map but I don't know where to paste it in the project, sorry for typing that much stuff

Comment: oh okay sorry i didnt get your question have you tried using google maps  python sdk [link](https://pypi.org/project/googlemaps/1.0.2/)

Comment: I read the link and it's helpful and easier but I wanted to know how to do it with the way above. However, thank you for your help